# How to load a partial view multiple times inside a view dynamically to capture different set of data simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a **Request View** which provides certain selection criteria for user build on MVC 4. Each selection requires additional set of inputs. I have consolidated all inputs(like text box, check box, etc) into a single partial view and decided to toggle the input controls based on each selection by the user and render the partial view multiple times.

Since user can make multiple selection on a single request I have to populate the partial simultaneously to the user for additional inputs. **Eg. If user made 5 selections in the Request View the partial view will be rendered 5 times below to capture 5 different set of additional inputs from user simultaneously.** Once user has entered his additional inputs and submit the request I have to pass the different set of inputs to controller for database action.
  Now my question is

1. How to use same **partial view** to get various set of inputs and bind with a model dynamically.
2. How to dynamically send different set of inputs rendered by same partial view to controller on a submit button action.

Technology Used:
MVC 4, Entity Framework 5

Answer (score 0):

My context was different, but I did something like that. The different views have to be able to all use the same generic model, but from what you describe, I wonder if this should not all be done client side, with JQuery and maybe the forms plugin.

In my case, I used this:
@model System.Xml.Linq.XElement

as model, so my controller method could return ANY XElement, the view was able to deal with it (knowing that a good number of sub elements had the same name). I set a Viewbag value, to be able to know from the view what type of XElement I was passing.

Hope this help,
Bernard